# Curve fitting with self-defined equation

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit the experimental data with a self-defined equation with MATLAB. The parameters I am interested are `y0`, `tau`, `D` and `C`. But I keep getting an error saying matrix dimensions must agree with the the following codes:

```
t = [0.00468
0.01277
0.05987
0.10316
0.18595
0.29252
0.39529
0.52136
0.68313
0.88818
1.08182
1.28688
1.45625
1.57471
1.73267
1.84685]
y = [9.02766
7.53879
5.3679
4.28093
3.09349
2.11005
1.63202
1.10224
0.77341
0.54506
0.42022
0.24363
0.21623
0.11575
0.11575
0.06704]

a1 = 10.86;
a2 = 15.5;
b1 = 8.74;
E = 1e15;


F = @(x,xdata)y0.*exp(-xdata./tau-(4.*pi./3).*E.*(1.7725).*(C.*xdata).^(1/2).*((1.+a1.*(D.*C.^(-1/3).*xdata.^(2/3)...
    )+a2.*(D.*C.^(-1/3).*xdata.^(2/3)).^2)./(1.+b1.*(D.*C.^(-1/3).*xdata.^(2/3))).^(3/4)));

X0 = [1 1e-3 1e-13 1e-30];
[x,resnorm,~,exitflag,output] = lsqcurvefit(F,X0,t,y)
```

The equation is described in the inserted graph and an example of using the functiong to fit the data is shown in another graph. Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us a [mcve]

Comment: Hi Ander, I don't have a verifiable example. The second graph is from literature. The main challenge is how to compile the function in MATLAB.

Comment: I dont want to reproduce the figure, I want to run your code. You say it trows an error, but we can not test your code without any data. Any code that trows an error that you want to fix must be runnable code. We should be able to copy paste it. The one you posted cant.

Comment: Hi Ander, I know what you mean. Sorry about that. But I don't know how to upload an excel file. Basically, the data can be fitted by a double exponential decay. You can generate double exponential decay data as a test. The reason why I want to use the equation described in the question to fit the data is to extract physical meanings.

Comment: Instead of that, give us some example yourself. No need to add an excel file, just some data as a variable. Ultimately if I need to spend 30 minutes doing work to fix your question I will be less likely to help. Make us helping you easy!

Comment: Hi Ander, I have uploaded test data to the question. Thank you for your help.